# Two questions regarding regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I currently use this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/' . $line . '/', '[x]\\0[/x]', $text);
```

`$line` is a simple regular expression:

```
https?://(?:.+?\.)?dailymotion\.com/video/[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

This is working fine so far. But there are two things that I need and I can't figure out, how to do that:

... I don't want to perform the replacement, if that string is contained within a `BBCode` i.e.

> [bla]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/bla]

or

> [bla=http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9]trololo[/bla]

or

> [bla='http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9']http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/bla]

The 2nd thing is, that I just want to match until the first space. This is what I currently use:

```
$text = preg_replace('/' . $line . '(?:[^ ]+)?/', '[x]\\0[/x]', $text);
```

I don't know, if I should do it like this or if there's a better way.

So, basically i'm just trying to match

> http://www.dailymotion.com/video/test4

from this:

`[tagx='http://www.dailymotion.com/video/test1']http://www.dailymotion.com/video/test2[/tagx] | [tagy]Hello http://www.dailymotion.com/video/test3 World[/tagy] | [tagz]Hello World[/tagz] http://www.dailymotion.com/video/test4`

EDIT:

This is, what i have so far (which works slightly):

`(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=))(\s|^))' . $line . '(?:[^ ]+)(?:(?<![[:punct:]])(\s|\.?$))?`

Comment: How does that regex work? You're using your delimiter `/` unescaped in the pattern: `https?://`

Comment: `$regex = str_replace('/', '\\/', $regex);`

Comment: You can use `\S` to match string until first blank-space character.

Comment: Instead of that hack, you should be using `preg_quote()` to escape other meta-characters so you don't have to manually.

Comment: Yeah, but that's currently my smallest problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookbehind assertions to do this.
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

By using the following lookbehind before $line

`(?<!\[bla]|\[bla=|\[bla=')`

it will match $link that is not starting with `[bla]`, `[bla=` and `[bla='`.

Comment: `(?<!\[|=|\'|")(?!\[\/)https?:\/\/(?:.+?\.)?dailymotion\.com\/video\/(?<ID>[A-Za-z0-9]+)`

That looks good, but the negative lookahead isn't working :(

With that, i could exclude everything that has [, ' and " before and [/ after it

Comment: @Whoknowsit You need to put the lookahead part after the $line part. `(?<!\[|=|\'|")https?:\/\/(?:.+?\.)?dailymotion\.com\/video\/(?<ID>[A-Za‌​-z0-9]+)(?!\[\/)`

Comment: That didn't work neither. I've edited the main post and added a better example.

Answer (score 0):

→ **Try this:**

```
$text = array();
$text[ 0 ] = "[bla]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/bla]";
$text[ 1 ] = "[bla=http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9]trololo[/bla]";
$text[ 2 ] = "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9";
$text[ 3 ] = "A http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9 B C";

$line = "/http:\/\/www.dailymotion\.com\/video\/[A-Za-z0-9]+/";

$tag = array();
$tag[ 0 ] = "/\[[A-Za-z]{1,12}\]http:\/\/www.dailymotion\.com\/video\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\[\/[A-Za-z]{1,12}\]/";
$tag[ 1 ] = "/\[[A-Za-z]{1,12}=http:\/\/www.dailymotion\.com\/video\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\][A-Za-z0-9]{0,}\[\/[A-Za-z]{1,12}\]/";

foreach( $text as $k=>$v ) {

    if( preg_match( $tag[ 0 ], $v ) == false && preg_match( $tag[ 1 ], $v ) == false ) {
        echo '!';
        $output = preg_replace( $line, '[x]\\0[/x]', $v );
    }
    else { $output = $v; };

    echo "Text #" . ( $k + 1 ) . ": {$output}<br />";

}
```

*Result:*

```
Text #1: [bla]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/bla]
Text #2: [bla=http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9]trololo[/bla]
!Text #3: [x]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/x]
!Text #4: A [x]http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xuams9[/x] B C
```